# How to make IList compatible to IEnumerable during lambda expression?

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

I'm trying to convert this:

```
ISession.Query<Question>()
    .Where(x => x.QuestionId == q.QuestionId)
    .FetchMany(x => x.Answers)
    .ToFuture();
```

To reflection type:

```
IQueryable<Question> query = ISession.Query<Question>().Where(string.Format("{0} = @0", "QuestionId"), q.QuestionId);
Type emType = typeof(NHibernate.Linq.EagerFetchingExtensionMethods);
MethodInfo mi = emType.GetMethod("FetchMany");

ParameterExpression paramEx = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Question), "x");
MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(paramEx, "Answers");         
LambdaExpression lambdaEx = Expression.Lambda (me, paramEx);            

// runtime error here
mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Question), typeof(Answer)).Invoke(emType, new object[] { query, lambdaEx });
```

The runtime error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Object of type 
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1
[System.Func`2[TestXXX.TheModels.Question,
System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[TestXXX.TheModels.Answer]]]' 

cannot be converted to type

'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1
[System.Func`2[TestXXX.TheModels.Question,
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TestXXX.TheModels.Answer]]]'.
```

POCO sample:

The Answers in Question is an IList, please don't advise to change IList to IEnumerable ;-)

```
public class Question
{
    public virtual int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual string QuestionText { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the method signature of FetchMany:

```
namespace NHibernate.Linq
{
    public static class EagerFetchingExtensionMethods
    {
        public static INhFetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated> Fetch<TOriginating, TRelated>(this IQueryable<TOriginating> query, Expression<Func<TOriginating, TRelated>> relatedObjectSelector);
        public static INhFetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated> FetchMany<TOriginating, TRelated>(this IQueryable<TOriginating> query, Expression<Func<TOriginating, IEnumerable<TRelated>>> relatedObjectSelector);
        public static INhFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> ThenFetch<TQueried, TFetch, TRelated>(this INhFetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> query, Expression<Func<TFetch, TRelated>> relatedObjectSelector);
        public static INhFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> ThenFetchMany<TQueried, TFetch, TRelated>(this INhFetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> query, Expression<Func<TFetch, IEnumerable<TRelated>>> relatedObjectSelector);
    }
}
```

What should be done so it's possible to pass an IList to NHibernate's FetchMany's IEnumerable during reflection?

Note: can pass IList to IEnumerable if we are not using reflection

Comment: `IList` implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Oded, your comment does not apply. He is not converting IList (which is falsely stated in the title). Here is converting an Expression of IList which is harder.

Comment: @Oded Yes IList has no problem with IEnumerable, they are compatible if using normal code, that was stated in the question, and in code(the very first code on the question, it compiles). During lambda reflection, the runtime complain though

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(paramEx, "Answers");
```

to this:

```
Expression me = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(paramEx, "Answers"), typeof(IEnumerable<Answer>));
```

The reason for the error you are receiving is that the delegate types of your lambda do not agree. We need to make the types compatible by artificially treating an `IList<T>` as an `IEnumerable<T>`.

This is kind of a hack as any proponent of dynamic languages would say ;-) Anyway, it reliably works.

Comment: This has an error during compile time: *Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'*

Comment: Did you try to fix it? Don't just give up.

Comment: Can you post your code then? How am I supposed to help you without knowing anything? If you want to get the solution you have to cooperate (which you are not doing).

Comment: Don't be hostile, I just did the solution(Expression.Convert) you suggested: **Expression me = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(paramEx, "Answers"), typeof(IEnumerable<Answer>));**  Try it out yourself, the compiler complains. I even do this: **(MemberExpression)Expression.Convert(...)**, And even this: **Expression.Convert(...) as MemberExpression**.  I posted my code in my question, it is complete, it's very cooperating

Comment: try this: "var me = Expression.Convert(..."

Comment: +1 Expression.Convert is new knowledge to me, **var me = Expression.Convert(...)** is valid. However, FetchMany just accepts a property expression only though. **Expression.Convert(..., typeof(IEnumerable<Answer>))** is akin to doing this: **.FetchMany(x => x.Answers as IEnumerable<Answer>)**, on which NHibernate's FetchMany lambda expression is not capable of accepting, it only accepts simple expression(i.e. property expression only), casting expression ultimately results to runtime error